# Deploy 2 different topologies on a single Nimbus with 2 different hardware

Tags: apache-storm, apache-storm-topology

I have 2 sets of storm topologies in use today, one is up 24/7, and does it's own work.
The other, is deployed on demand, and handles a much bigger loads of data.
As of today, we have N supervisors instances, all from the same type of hardware (CPU/RAM), I'd like my on demand topology to run on stronger hardware, but as far as I know, there's no way to control which supervisor is assigned to which topology.
So if I can't control it, it's possible that the 24/7 topology would assign one of the stronger workers to itself.

Any ideas, if there is such a way?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can control which topologies go where. This is the job of the scheduler.

You very likely want either the isolation scheduler or the resource aware scheduler. See https://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Storm-Scheduler.html and https://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Resource_Aware_Scheduler_overview.html.

The isolation scheduler lets you prevent Storm from running any other topologies on the machines you use to run the on demand topology. The resource aware scheduler would let you set the resource requirements for the on demand topology, and preferentially assign the strong machines to the on demand topology. See the priority section at https://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Resource_Aware_Scheduler_overview.html#Topology-Priorities-and-Per-User-Resource.